# Proxy software to run your java programs, and allow console interaction with them over the network, to avoid long process startup times?

Tags: java

A while ago I ran across a project that did something like this, and I cannot find it now anywhere.  The idea was this thing would run your java program for you, and you'd interact with it over the network.  Presumably text-only programs, though I didn't get all the details (I'd probably remember it better if I had).  This would allow you to use the output of a java program on a php web page, say, and avoid taking the java program startup hit every time.

Does anyone know of this project or anything similar?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of java programs? In a way you have just described Tomcat, though i assume this is not what you meant.

Comment: I should have mentioned, asadmin from Glassfish.  I'd like to query it to get a list of deployed applications, to display in a PHP web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nailgun](http://martiansoftware.com/nailgun/index.html) might be what you're looking for:

> Nailgun is a client, protocol, and server for running Java programs from the command line without incurring the JVM startup overhead. Programs run in the server (which is implemented in Java), and are triggered by the client (written in C), which handles all I/O.